# Applescript or shellscript to delete config file?

Tags: shell, applescript

Please suggest how do I delete a config file with permissions; with my script's .cfg file is not deleting.
I tried with Applescript and shell script both, but it's not working, and also it's not asking for permissions as well.

```
tell application "System Events"
    delete  file "/Library/Application Support/Macromedia/abc.cfg"
end tell

do shell script "rm -f /Library/Application Support/Macromedia/abc.cfg"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.. i just missed single quotes..

```
do shell script "rm -f '/Library/Application Support/Macromedia/abc.cfg'"
```

Comment: It's better to use quoted form of instead of trying to quote yourself.